# pyqt5,custom widget can not show

Tags: pyqt5

i want a simple widget like C2, but C2 did not show?

```
class C2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(100, 100)
        self.setMinimumSize(100, 100)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 380, 30)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: blue;')


app = QApplication([])
window = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Top'))
layout.addWidget(QPushButton('Bottom'))
layout.addWidget(C2())
window.setLayout(layout)
window.show()
app.exec()
```

i custom a widget with blur background-color, but it can not show.

Answer (score 0):

You want to inherit a `QLabel`, not a `QWidget`.

The only line that needs a modification is `class C2(QLabel):`

[image]

Comment: but, Why  the qwidget can't be displayed?

Comment: Subclassing from QLabel is pointless as it also takes along a plethora of unnecessary functions. The bare minimum would be to use QFrame (from which QLabel inherits), but since QWidget subclasses allow to properly show the style sheet (either by implementing `paintEvent()` with QStyle or using the `Qt.WA_StyledBackground` attribute), that would be pointless anyway.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you, good to know. I have softwares to update ^^